# Close Excel file without saving prompt and without saving

Tags: excel, vba

I tried everything but it still prompts me the saving dialog!
I tried the most obvious:

```
Sub Auto_Close()

    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

I placed the code in `ThisWorkbook` module and it doesn't work.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: still prompts me the dialog

Comment: `Auto_Close` doesn't belong in the `ThisWorkbook` module. Should be in a regular module.

Comment: Strange - works just fine for me. Oh I just called my routine `Test` - didnt realize you were hooking into an event.

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: Please put your code in a regular module. Also, `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` should come *before* closing (based on an edit you made that was later reversed).

Comment: this worked. thank you to both of you guys.